# conditional className ternary operator rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a div with conditional className style applying.

`<div className={type === "myType" && classes.myClass}>`

So I want to apply `myClass` if type is `myType`. But if type is not `myType` I got a warning:

```
Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `className`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: className="false" or className={value.toString()}.

If you used to conditionally omit it with className={condition && value}, pass className={condition ? value : undefined} instead.
    at div
```

In that cases I usually replaced my condition like this:

`<div className={type === "myType" ? classes.myClass : null}>`

But warning recommend to me use `undefined` instead of `null`.

So I am asking what is better to use and why?

Comment: `A && B` will return `A` if `A` is falsy, and `false` is not a valid value for `className`. Nor is `null` apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is neither, as the class name is a string, so the best practice would be to return the same type of data.

The code would be just as follow then:
`<div className={type === "myType" ? classes.myClass : ""}>`

Comment: A value can be undefined, but a string cannot. `""` is not undefined.

Comment: true, bad choice of words, in the whole paragraph I meant that "" is falsy while an non-empty string is truthy.

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx).

This is much cleaner than a native solution suggested by the warning, clsx allows you to do the following:

```
import clsx from 'clsx';
 
// Strings (variadic)
clsx('foo', true && 'bar', 'baz');
//=> 'foo bar baz'
 
// Objects
clsx({ foo:true, bar:false, baz:isTrue() });
//=> 'foo baz'
 
// Objects (variadic)
clsx({ foo:true }, { bar:false }, null, { '--foobar':'hello' });
//=> 'foo --foobar'
 
// Arrays
clsx(['foo', 0, false, 'bar']);
//=> 'foo bar'
 
// Arrays (variadic)
clsx(['foo'], ['', 0, false, 'bar'], [['baz', [['hello'], 'there']]]);
//=> 'foo bar baz hello there'
 
// Kitchen sink (with nesting)
clsx('foo', [1 && 'bar', { baz:false, bat:null }, ['hello', ['world']]], 'cya');
//=> 'foo bar hello world cya'
```

Comment: not sure if a simple case like this would require an entire library...

Comment: @Alex This library has one function and it's very small (40 lines). Yana didn't show us the whole project, but I suspect any realistic project will have multiple class names and condition attached.